# Should I specify the proxy in the Model or the Store?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4

I'm relatively new to cross-platform mobile development, and recently have been going through some basic tutorials on how to use Sencha Touch in my app. I have been confused by what seems to me as inconsistency in their methodology. So here is my question:

I am using the MVC design pattern. When defining a proxy for storing data in an app, should I do this in the Model or in the Store? I have seen both done and am not sure which is better, or the cases when each should be used. The following are examples of what I mean:

Proxy defined in the **Store**:

```js
App.stores.users = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'User',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
         type: 'localstorage',
         id: 'sencha-users'
    }
});
```

Proxy defined in the **Model**:

```js
App.models.User = Ext.regModel('User', {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'email',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'firstname',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'lastname',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'password',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'sencha-users'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They leave it up to you because it's an implementation decision. The convenience of having it tied to the model dictates a strong one-to-one relationship.

In ExtJS 3.3.1 and below, the proxy was always tied to the store.  It wasn't until Sencha Touch and ExtJS 4 that they allowed you to tie directly to the model.

The best reason I can think of to tie it to the model is to keep it self-contained.

> Defining Proxies directly on a Model is a new approach in version 4—its main benefit is that we can easily load and save Model data without creating a Store, as we did in ExtJS 3.

**Edit**

Sorry if I was a little high level with my explanation.

Think of a *Store* as a Collection of *Models*.

The store can be self-aware on how to populate these models by using the proxy defined to the store.  **Or** the Model may already know how to populate itself by defining the proxy to it instead.

Please let me know if I didn't clarify well enough. :)